# Android download manager streaming with GET

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to get a streamed file with the Android DownloadManager with HTTP GET,
I'm getting this status and reason from the downloadManager:

STATUS_FAILED
ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME

is it possible to use it to download streamed files?

thanks.